# Postgres: how to calculate temp file space requirement

Tags: database, postgresql

During execution of query I get error:
`temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (<some num>kB)`.

How can I calculate the required temp file storage of a query (using EXPLAIN ANALYZE)?

I require method of calculating temp file disk usage, so that I can tune my query to lower the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go would be to disable `temp_file_limit` and set `log_temp_files = 0`. Then you would see the size of the temporary files in the log (and in the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output).

But if I were you, I'd look at the `EXPLAIN` output and find the `Sort` that promises to be very big and see what I can to to avoid it. The optimizer will avoid plans with very large hashes, and bitmaps won't ever exceed `work_mem`, so it must be a large sort that is creating temporary files.